# Getting 'sudo: unknown user: hadoop' and 'sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin error' on Google Cloud Platform while running hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

I am trying to deploy the sample Hadoop app provided by Google at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop on Google Cloud Platform.

I followed all the setup instructions given there step-by-step. I was able to setup the environment and start the cluster successfully. But I am not able to run the MapReduce part.
I am executing this command on my terminal:

```
./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py mapreduce <project ID> <bucket name> [--prefix <prefix>]
--input gs://<input directory on Google Cloud Storage>  \
--output gs://<output directory on Google Cloud Storage>  \
--mapper sample/shortest-to-longest-mapper.pl  \
--reducer sample/shortest-to-longest-reducer.pl  \
--mapper-count 5  \
--reducer-count 1
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
sudo: unknown user: hadoop
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 230, in <module>
main()
File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 226, in main
ComputeClusterForHadoop().ParseArgumentsAndExecute(sys.argv[1:])
File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 222, in ParseArgumentsAndExecute
params.handler(params)
File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 51, in MapReduce
gce_cluster.GceCluster(flags).StartMapReduce()
File "/home/ubuntu-gnome/Hadoop-sample-app/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop-master/gce_cluster.py", line 545, in StartMapReduce
input_dir, output_dir)
File "/home/ubuntu-gnome/Hadoop-sample-app/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop-master/gce_cluster.py", line 462, in _StartScriptAtMaster
raise RemoteExecutionError('Remote execution error')
gce_cluster.RemoteExecutionError: Remote execution error
```

Since I have followed all the steps given there as-it-is, I am not able to understand why this issue is arising?

Is the 'hadoop' user actually not created in the previous scripts executed, or there is a problem with user permissions? Or the problem is somewhere else?

Please help me with this error..!!  I am stuck here and can't proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup process is normally expected to create the user 'hadoop' automatically; it's done inside [startup-script.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop/blob/master/startup-script.sh#L76) on line 75-76:

```
# Set up user and group
groupadd --gid 5555 hadoop
useradd --uid 1111 --gid hadoop --shell /bin/bash -m hadoop
```

It's possible that some portion of the setup actually failed.

That said, the sample you're referencing, while still useful as a starting point if you're writing your own Python application which interacts with the GCE API directly, is deprecated as a way to deploy Hadoop on Google Compute Engine. If you actually want to use Hadoop, you should use the Google-supported deployment tool [bdutil and its associated quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/). There are some similarities in the cluster which gets deployed, including the setup of a user `hadoop`. A key difference, however, is that `bdutil` will also include and configure the [GCS connector for Hadoop](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector) so that your MapReduce can operate directly against the data in GCS rather than needing to copy it into HDFS first.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yah, after analyzing a lot, it feels like the script startup-script.sh was never executed during the setup phase. In my case then, I manually created the hadoop group and hadoop user. But still there were issues with further instructions (hadoop directory read-write permissions). Anyways, I then deployed using bdutil tool as you suggested and it was quite easy to do that. Thanks again, @DennisHuo!